# How do you properly use pthread_cond_timedwait() without receiving a ETIMEDOUT error?

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, udp, pthreads

I am really new to the pthread and time classes and I am currently doing a homework assignment in which I have to send packets of strings at specific times using the pthread_cond_timedwait() command. The command is called in a thread declared to the sendPackets() function; a function that will send all packets to the target IP. The thread initializes just fine but after storing the time that I  would like the thread to unblock and uses it as an argument in timedwait(), the function returns the ETIMEDOUT error. Now I am aware that my condition variable could be (and probably is) the reason why it is timing out. I have tried to do research on this function but no matter how much searching I did I haven't found any solutions to my problem (and this is probably because of something simple I overlooked).

Established as global variables are the mutex object and the pthread_cond_t object. They have a global scope so that all threads can access them. I also have established a struct in order to hold information about the set of packets that i'm sending:

```
struct info{
    int socket;
    int size;
    int count;
    float interval;
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr;
};

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t thread = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

After the CLA's are read in (these determine things such as packet count, interval, size in bytes, and server port), I check to see if the program was called as a server or a client (the program is supposed to be interchangeable depending on the presence of the flag -S). If the main method is a client, it goes into the following if statement and initializes the sendPackets() thread. An info pointer is created and initialized and casted to a void pointer in order to pass arguments to the sendPackets() function.

```
if(isClient){
        /*Create a datagram UDP socket*/
        if((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0){
            DieWithError("socket() failed\n");
        }

        /* Construct the server address structure */
        memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));
        echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);
        echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);

        enum threads {sender=0,receiver};

        struct info *packets = (struct info*)malloc(sizeof(struct info));

        packets->size = size;
        packets->count = ping_packet_count;
        packets->socket = sock;
        packets->echoServAddr = echoServAddr;
        packets->interval = ping_interval;

        pthread_t tid[2];

        int a,b; //Thread creation return variables
        a = pthread_create(&(tid[sender]),NULL,&sendPackets,(void*)packets);

        pthread_join(tid[sender], NULL);
        //pthread_join(tid[receiver], NULL);

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    }
```

Once the thread begins, it acquires the lock and proceeds to carry out its code. Start time is the time the program had begun processing packets. Current time represents the time that the program is at when calculating when to send the next packet, and send packet is the start time + the delay for each packet (sendTime = start_time + [id#] * packet_interval). After testing the code a bit, ive noticed the program doesn't time out until the time specified by sendTime(), which even further shows me that I am just doing something wrong with my condition variable since im so unfamiliar with them. Last little note: clk_id is a macro I had set to CLOCK_REALTIME.

```
void* sendPackets(void *p){
printf("Starting sendPackets function...\n");
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
printf("Sender has aquired lock\n\n");

struct info *packet = (struct info*)p;

printf("Packet Details: Socket: %d Size %d Count %d Interval:%f\n\n",packet->socket,packet->size,packet->count,packet->interval);

    struct timespec startTime = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < packet->count; i++){
        struct timespec sendTime = {0};
        struct timespec currentTime = {0};
        float delay = packet->interval * i;
        int delayInt = (int) delay;

        unsigned char echoString[packet->size];
        char strbffr[200] = "";
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(packet->echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr),strbffr,200*sizeof(char));

        sendTime.tv_sec = 0;
        sendTime.tv_nsec = 0;

        printf("PacketID:%d Delay:%f DelayInt:%d\n",i,delay,delayInt);

        if(i == 0){
            clock_gettime(clk_id,&startTime);
            startTime.tv_sec+=1;
        }
        clock_gettime(clk_id,&currentTime);

        sendTime.tv_sec = startTime.tv_sec + delayInt;
        sendTime.tv_nsec = startTime.tv_nsec + (int)((delay - delayInt) * 1000000000);
    
        printf("startTime: tv_sec = %d tv_nsec = %d\n",(int)startTime.tv_sec,(int)startTime.tv_nsec);
        printf("sendTime: tv_sec = %d tv_nsec = %d\n",(int)sendTime.tv_sec,(int)sendTime.tv_nsec);
        printf("currentTime: tv_sec = %d tv_nsec = %d\n\n",(int)currentTime.tv_sec,(int)currentTime.tv_nsec);
        int r_wait;

        if((r_wait = pthread_cond_timedwait(&thread,&lock,&sendTime)) != 0){
            clock_gettime(clk_id,&currentTime);
            printf("currentTime: tv_sec = %d tv_nsec = %d\n\n",(int)currentTime.tv_sec,(int)currentTime.tv_nsec);
            printf("Received error for timedwait:%s\n",strerror(r_wait));
            exit(1);
        }
        if (sendto(packet->socket, echoString, packet->size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &packet->echoServAddr, sizeof(packet->echoServAddr)) != packet->size){
            DieWithError("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected\n");
        }
        printf("Sent %d to IP:%s\n",i,strbffr);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < packet->count; i++){
        unsigned char echoString[packet->size];
        char strbffr[200] = "";
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(packet->echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr),strbffr,200*sizeof(char));
        if (sendto(packet->socket, echoString, packet->size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &packet->echoServAddr, sizeof(packet->echoServAddr)) != packet->size){
            DieWithError("sendto() sent a different number of bytes than expected\n");
        }
        printf("Sent %d to IP:%s\n",i,strbffr);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Sender has released lock\n");
    printf("Yielding Sender\n\n");
    sched_yield();
```

I am aware that this is a lot of stuff to take in. If there is any other part of my code that you would like to take a look at that I haven't mentioned then please feel free to post a comment stating what you would like to see. I'm pretty confident this is every data structure in my code that is relevant to the issue, however, I could always be wrong.

[Here is an image of the output of my program from the print statements I have listed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdbjd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `pthread_cond_timedwait()` as a timer: you don't expect the CV to be signaled (which would terminate the wait early), but rather for the calling thread to be suspended for the full specified timeout.

In that case, `ETIMEDOUT` is exactly what you should expect when everything works as intended.  You should check for that and accept it, and you should perform appropriate handling if you see anything else.  In particular, pthreads CV's can exhibit spurious wakeup, so if your `pthread_cond_wait()` ever returns normally then you need to loop back and wait again to ensure that the full timeout elapses before you proceed.

In short, you should not view an `ETIMEDOUT` return code as indicating that something went wrong, but rather that (for your particular purposes) everything went right.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot more sense. Thank you for giving me that clarification I feel like such an idiot. Reading the documentation for functions you've never used before is really rough sometimes so I am glad that you were able to explain that to me.